# knockout js - How to change list color when click the list under foreach statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am using one of the latest version of knockout js and have some issue with changing color when click.
I would like to change the color of a list when a user clicks one of the list and keep the color of the list until a user clicks another list, but no luck so far.

one of my ideas is to get the index value from clicked list and add css class which have inverted colors (color: black, background-color: white).

**html**

```
<div class="left_pane">
    <div class="location_list" data-bind="foreach: locations">
        <div data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.is_selected, css: {selected: $parent.current_index == $index }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.left_pane {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;

    height: 850px;
}

.location_list {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.selected {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

**js**

```
var locations = [

    {'title': 'title01'},
    {'title': 'title02'},
    {'title': 'title03'},
    {'title': 'title04'},
    {'title': 'title05'}

];

function InitViewModel() {
    // main viewModel
    var self = this;

    self.current_index = ko.observable('');

    console.log(self.current_index());

    self.is_selected = function(data, event) {
        // save clicked row's index to current_index.
       self.current_index($(event.target).index());
      //  self.current_index($(event.target).index());
        console.log(self.current_index());
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new InitViewModel());
```

Thank you for your support and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! I find that it is simply easier to track the selected item in it's own observable, and set it to the clicked item. You can use your same method to change the class to `selected`. If you need to select multiples I normally use an object that tracks the selected status. (i.e. `'title': 'title01', selected: false }`) and then simply change the click function to `location.selected(true)`.

The biggest change from your code to mine is not bothering to trace back `location` items and just take what it is. If it matches perfect, if not you have what you need.

```js
function InitViewModel() {
  // main viewModel
  var self = this;

  self.Selected = ko.observable("");

  self.locations = [{
      'title': 'title01'
    }, {
      'title': 'title02'
    }, {
      'title': 'title03'
    }, {
      'title': 'title04'
    }, {
      'title': 'title05'
    }
  ];

  self.current_index = ko.observable('');

  console.log(self.current_index());

  self.select = function(location) {
   self.Selected(location);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new InitViewModel());
```

```css
.left_pane {
  background-color: #BBB;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 850px;
}

.location_list {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.selected {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="left_pane">
  <div class="location_list" data-bind="foreach: locations">
    <div data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.select, css: {selected: $data === $parent.Selected() }"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```